# Maven 2 dependency problem

Tags: java, maven-2

I'm merging two projects into one(mergin project1 into project2). Now I'm going to copy all dependencies from project1 pom into project2 pom, like :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

And some others. The build is successful the thing in eclipse annoys me so much like when hovering over `import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException`:

```
The import org.apache.commons.configuration cannot be resolved
```

But the build still succeds, what can I do to get rid of these?

Answer (score 2):

If you use m2eclipse, you need to click `Maven -> Update Dependencies`.

Otherwise I guess you need to regenerate the Eclipse project with `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing 'mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse'.  That will force maven to delete all of the old eclipse configurations for your project and rebuild them from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to edit POM by inserting whitespace and saving it. It should trigger rebuilding of the project. There is also a "Refresh Dependencies" option in m2eclipse plugin. 
I had similiar problems when I used Eclipse integrated with Maven and the 1st technique usually helped.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a build is done successfully and ensure that on your `Package Explorer` the org.apache.commons jar is found under the `Maven Dependencies` section (given you have m2eclipse plugin installed in your eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

What version of Eclipse, mvn and m2eclipse?  Might want to double-check those.

You shouldn't need to do mvn eclipse:eclipse anymore - that's obsolete.  You can try deleting your Eclipse project files and reopening the project (settings, project, classpath).